# How to detach branch from the parent in git?

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to detach `develop` branch from `master`. The `develop` branch was intended to be separate branch not a child of `master`. So I need the following:

```
A---B---C (master)
         \
          D (develop)

into:

A---B---C (master)

D (develop)
```

The intention to move into Gitflow workflow at existing project. Even if you think something isn't logical here - I just want to know how to do it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# preserves branch config, remotes, reflog, merge options, what not
git rev-parse develop >.git/info/grafts
git filter-branch -- develop
rm .git/info/grafts
```

or

```
# preserves branch config etc
git log -1 --format=%B develop \ 
| git commit-tree develop: \
| xargs git update-ref refs/heads/develop
```

or

```
# wipes branch config etc and you'll have to redo the commit message
git checkout develop^0
git branch -D develop
git checkout --orphan develop
```

or

```
# preserves branch config etc
git checkout develop
git checkout --orphan junk
git commit -C develop
git checkout -B develop
git branch -D junk
```

Comment: The last way the most simple and clear to me!)  thanks!)

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a copy of commit `D` with one change: the new commit has no parents (i.e., is a root commit of its own, rather like `A`).

There are two easy ways to do this using "normal user" git commands:

#### Explicitly make new orphan branch

(This method has more manual work but I think is clearer.  It's ultimately the same as the second method below, except that it keeps the reflog entry for the original branched-from-`B` commit `D`.)

```
$ git checkout develop   # if needed
$ git checkout --orphan ndevelop
$ git commit
```

(You can combine the first two lines into:

```
$ git checkout --orphan ndevelop develop
```

which sets up the index based on `develop` before setting you up on the new, as-yet-to-be-created branch `ndevelop`.  It's the `git commit` step that creates the branch, using the contents of the index, which is why we want to start from commit `D`: it has the right index entries.)

You can re-use the existing commit-D commit message (add `-c develop` or `-C develop` to the commit command), if you like.

Finally, delete the old branch-name `develop` and rename `ndevelop` to `develop`:

```
$ git branch -D develop
$ git branch -m develop
```

#### Use `git rebase -i --root`

Starting on branch develop (check it out if needed, or just add it to the rebase command which simply checks it out for you), run `git rebase -i --root`:

```
$ git checkout develop
$ git rebase -i --root
```

or:

```
$ git rebase -i --root develop
```

These bring up your editor, proposing to copy commits `A`, `B`, and `D` (three `pick` lines).  Then just delete all but the last commit `D`, write out the modified instructions, and exit the editor.  The rebase will create an empty orphan branch (same as we did in the explicit version) and copy commit `D` to it, then alter `develop` to point to the new empty branch.

(We could have done this last step ourselves in the explicit version, with `git branch -f develop ndevelop`, then deleted `ndevelop` instead, which would give us exactly the same outcome, retaining the reflog.)

Comment: I didn't think rebase --root worked that way. Won't the rebase copy only the changes in D?

Comment: @jthill: normally it would (get changes), but in this case it seemed to work (I tested it).  In particular the `rebase --root` action seems to modify the first cherry-pick to be a commit instead, using the tree from the first-picked commit.  I took a brief look at the interactive rebase script and it's not obvious how this actually works... **edit** aha, it's because the startup script (exec-path/rebase) sets a fake starting point of `$empty_tree` and a special `squash_onto` variable.  So it diffs the starting pick against an empty tree.

Comment: I didn't get idea with `rebase --root`. If I delete all lines preceding initial commit of `develop` and start to rebase - the result will be orphan branch and commits of `master` remain untouched?

Comment: @TimurFayzrakhmanov: rebase *never* changes *any* commits.  (It can't, due to the nature of a git commit.)  Instead, it makes *copies* of commits, and when it is done, it moves the current branch label so that instead of pointing to the original commit(s), it now points to the copies.  It does not move any *other* branch labels, so only the current branch gets rebased.  (If you didn't delete the lines for commits `A` and `B`, rebase would copy those as well and you'd have a new root commit `A'`, with new commit `B'` pointing to `A'`, and new commit `D'` pointing to `B'`.)